# Reading and parsing text from a text file in C

Tags: c

Question:

I am trying to read each line from a file (.txt file below) while storing its contents in the appropriate variables. The problem occurs when compiling. I am told there is a segmentation fault but am not sure why this occurring.

tester1.txt file(disregard spaces)

> 1/12/04 Jones, John $31.11
>
> 12/22/03 Dickinson, Tony $5.04
>
> 12/15/03 Lee, Jerry $21.12
>
> 12/19/03 Kahn, Chris $83.15
>
> 1/31/04 Bills, Mike $32.00
>
> 1/15/04 Lake, Jeff $6.66

Code:

```
int main() {

      int month, day, year;
      float money;
      char *lastname, *firstname;
      static const char filename[] = "tester1.txt";

      FILE *file = fopen (filename, "r");

      if (file != NULL) {  
        char line [128]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL) {

          sscanf(line,"%d/%d/%d %s, %s $%f", &month, &day, &year, lastname,
        firstname, &money);
          printf("%d/%d/%d %s, %s $%.2f\n", month, day, year, lastname,
        firstname, money );
          // printf("valid: %s\n", line);  
          //  fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
        }
        fclose (file);
      }
      else {
        perror (filename); /* why didn't the file open? */
      }
      return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to allocate memory for the strings, you can't just declare them as pointers:

```
char lastname[256], firstname[256];
```

Also, in the `scanf` you can specify anything but comma (and space), otherwise the comma is also read as a part of the string:

```
sscanf(line,"%d/%d/%d %[^, ], %s $%f", &month, &day, &year, 
                lastname, firstname, &money);
```

Comment: Thank you for that fix. After I changed my code I am getting faulty output:                                                   1/12/4 Jones,,  $0.00
12/22/3 Dickinson,,  $0.00
12/15/3 Lee,,  $0.00
12/19/3 Kahn,,  $0.00
1/31/4 Bills,,  $0.00
1/15/4 Lake,,  $0.00                     What is the issue?

Comment: @CRU26, also, if you are going to store these in someplace, you need to use `malloc` and `strcpy` to store them in different buffers.

Comment: I have called malloc for creating a node in the tree structure I have written elsewhere. Does this mean that I also need to call malloc for lastname and firstname? Otherwise, why would using strcpy help?

Comment: Yes, you need to allocate space for them for each name in the structure also. Otherwise they will all have the address of the same variables (which you overwrite for each line). Don't forget to allocate 1 more character then the strlen (for the null terminator).

Comment: Do I allocate space for the name in my main or in my node.c file which has all the standard methods for a tree structure. I'm not exactly sure what you mean since I thought I had already done this when creating space for a new treenode.

Comment: What I mean is, if you do `node.firstname = firstname`, all pointers will have the same value. Rather, you want `node.firstname = malloc(...); strcpy(node.firstname, firstname);...`

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to correct the name issue. The only problem is now my 'lookup' method in my node class doesn't find an identical node in the tree.

Comment: See:  struct treenode *test = talloc(1,12,04,"Jones","John",31.11);.....printf("IN TREE: %d\n",lookup(root1,test)); return 1 if in tree, 0 otherwise. root1 stores all of the lines in a tree full of these nodes. When comparing this test treenode it returns 0 when I call lookup when it should really return 1.

Comment: @CRU26, please ask another question, this question is getting out of context.

Answer (score 0):

First you have allocate memory for the strings, like perreal said. Then you have to change the sscanf

```
char str_money[100];

sscanf(line,"%d/%d/%d %s%s%s",
       &month, &day, &year, lastname, firstname, str_money);
```

Because if you scanf %f, you will not get that tidy float number. And scanf %s only stop at space

Comment: Thank you! It seems that if I store the text lines according to these variables (into nodes for a tree) then a problem occurs with the firstname and lastname variables repeating or overwriting each other. The inorder treeprint of these variables according to the amount of money is: 12/22/03 Lake, Jeff $5.04 1/15/04 Lake, Jeff $6.66 12/15/03 Lake, Jeff $21.12 1/12/04 Lake, Jeff $31.11 1/31/04 Lake, Jeff $32.00 12/19/03 Lake, Jeff $83.15